# How do I invoke a dup2() syscall from PHP ?

Tags: php, linux, file-descriptor, system-calls

There is an [`eio_dup2()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eio-dup2.php) function from [Eio PECL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.eio.php) but I am confused about all the async and event-loop stuff and I rather prefer to work with the [standard syscall](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2). Any insights ?